# Flask Python3 Вызвать асинхронную функцию

Tags: python-3.x, flask, асинхронность, asyncio

У меня есть код который обрабатывает вебхуки.

```
@app.route("/", methods=["POST"])
async def route():
    k = request.form.keys()
    keys = ""
    for key in k:
        keys += key
    j = json.loads(keys)
    if j["transactionStatus"] == "Approved":
        await no_webhook.confirm_purchase(j['orderReference'])
        print("Finished")
    else:
        pass
    hmac_string = j['orderReference'] + ";" + 'accept' + 'time'
    r = {"orderReference": j['orderReference'], "status": "accept", "time": 1415379863,"signature": hmac.new(secret_key.encode(), hmac_string.encode(), hashlib.md5).hexdigest()}
    rr = jsonify(r)
    return rr
```

Если проходит платёж, то должна вызываться следующая функция:

```
async def confirm_purchase(reference):
    today = datetime.datetime.today()
    return True
```

Flask постоянно возвращает какую то лабуду когда пытаюсь сделать через asyncio.run и через loop.
Есть какие нибудь решения?

Comment: а разве flask  не фреймворк для создания СИНХРОННЫХ веб-приложений?

Comment: @Vadim.Sharoikin там можно его запустить на асинхронном лупе - тогда будет доступен create task